# Remove reference to stackstatus.net in "site down" message, or update it

Tags: discussion

Note: I am not reporting that the meta sites were down, nor that the main site was down. That much was apparent and needs no further discussion.

My complaint instead is about the message shown while Meta Stack Overflow was in "read-only mode", namely:

> This site is currently in read-only mode; we’ll return with full functionality soon. Follow [@StackStatus](https://twitter.com/StackStatus) or visit our [status blog](http://stackstatus.net/) for more info.

Not having used my Twitter account in many years, I opted to go to the status blog, where I found the latest entry to have been from August 3, 2016, or "5 months ago". Suffice it to say that was less than helpful. I bit the bullet and went to Twitter and found that many, many things have happened since the third of August.

I understand that keeping a blog updated is a pain. One of my own blogs has shown an "error connecting to database" for several years now. But I'm not in charge of informing thousands of users of the status of a very popular website.

I think that perhaps just a rephrasing of the message would be adequate:

> This site is currently in read-only mode; we’ll return with full functionality soon. Follow [@StackStatus](https://twitter.com/StackStatus) for up-to-date info or visit our [status blog](http://stackstatus.net/) for more in-depth info of past outages.

Maybe this isn't a big deal. Maybe I'm just old and don't get that everyone else looks to Twitter first and don't even read blogs. Please, do let me know if that's the case and I'll go back to electrifying my lawn...

Comment: Somewhat related on MSE: [Please keep the support Twitter stream and blog up to date](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270394/please-keep-the-support-twitter-stream-and-blog-up-to-date/270395)

Comment: Good find @JoshCaswell. I'm a bit more patient and hopefully somewhat less caustic than Lightness :).

Comment: You don't need a Twitter account to see a Twitter account's tweets.

Comment: Thanks @ale, I know that *now* ;).

Comment: Another related [feature request of mine on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232079/can-stackstatus-tweets-be-posted-to-stackstatus-net-automatically)